# Any Performance bottlenecks in Sitecore (9.x) Security Feature in CD

Tags: sitecore-api

We are working on oauth login with external IDP and we will create the virtual users after validation (Sitecore 9.3). Based on the claims, we will set certain (extranet) roles and custom profile attributes to the virtual user. With that, we are planning to leverage Sitecore rules to restrict content item based on certain roles and profile attributes.

Earlier in Sitecore 6.6 and 7.5, I have faced performance issue (another client) with AccessResultCache and we had disabled security (link below) for web database as the site did not use Sitecore security feature. But for the current client, we are planning to use Sitecore security feature heavily. Did anyone face any performance issues with Sitecore security + Virtual users + Sitecore rules in Sitecore 9.x recently? Any insights?

https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/do-you-really-need-accessresultcache-on-cd-servers-if-no-then-disable-it-for-better-performance/

Comment: I implemented a ADB2C based Oauth with Sitecore 9.1 , the start of the implemenation we did face some issues. But no issues in Prod.